# RaspberryPi - Execute samsungctl within php

Tags: php, samsung

I'm trying to run the command:
<"samsungctl --host 192.168.1.157 --method websocket KEY_MUTE">
in order to control my samsung smart TV, using shell_exec(<"command">);
samsungctl is a python program that controls Samsung TV's

From terminal the command executes just fine and the TV indeed Mutes.
As I understand the problem is that, from php the command is executed with user www-data and the problem is the permissions of the user www-data.

I've tried various solutions as i found them here:
https://nocurve.com/2018/04/23/running-python-script-from-php-as-www-data/
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=50225
Also I've tried to control samsung TV directly from  php using this:
https://gist.github.com/hkalina/b70dff4369ff2f0a2afe
And many more similar solutions, but all of them unfortunately failed.

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you

Comment: Might want to read about `/etc/sudoers`. That should give you a good starting point, at least for one possible solution.

Comment: When you tried something, and it failed, It would be nice to tell WHY it failed. (That info can be a pretty goud info for someone searching for the same info)